# Error while building unity project (having firebase) in Android studio

Tags: android, firebase, unity-game-engine, gradle

I am working on a unity project for Android platform. I had to use gradle(new) method for building because the number of field references exceeded than what was allowed. I am also using firebase and FbSDK in the project. However, I am not able to build it properly. So, I thought of exporting the project and build it using Android studio. However, I am getting an error while building the project. The error is

> No matching client found for package name 'com.google.firebase.unity' .

According to firebase, I need to add the following lines in the gradle files.

```
1. Project-level build.gradle (<project>/build.gradle):

buildscript {
dependencies {
// Add this line
classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
}


2. App-level build.gradle (<project>/<app-module>/build.gradle):

dependencies {
// Add this line
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
}
...
// Add to the bottom of the file
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

These are my gradle files:
project/build.gradle

```
  // GENERATED BY UNITY. REMOVE THIS COMMENT TO PREVENT OVERWRITING WHEN EXPORTING AGAIN

    buildscript {
    repositories {
    jcenter()
    google()
}

dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.0'
    classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.2.0'
}
}

allprojects {
 repositories {
  flatDir {
    dirs 'libs'
     }
  }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-sdk-4.23.0', ext:'aar')
    compile(name: 'facebook-android-wrapper-7.10.1', ext:'aar')
    compile project(':Firebase')
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

defaultConfig {
    multiDexEnabled true
    targetSdkVersion 27
    applicationId 'com.DefaultCompany.Data_Collection'
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
signingConfigs { release {
    storeFile file('C:\\Users\\vaish\\.android\\debug.keystore')
    storePassword 'qwerty123'
    keyAlias 'datacollection'
    keyPassword 'qwerty123'
} }

buildTypes {
    debug {
        jniDebuggable true
    }
    release {
        // Set minifyEnabled to true if you want to run ProGuard on your project
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-unity.txt'
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}


}
```

project/Firebase/build.gradle

```
buildscript {
        repositories {
        mavenCentral()
        google()
    }
dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.0'
}
}

apply plugin: 'android-library'

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'bin', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:12.0.0'
}

 android {
    sourceSets {
        main {
            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
            //java.srcDirs = ['src']
             res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
       }
}

compileSdkVersion 27
buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
defaultConfig {
    targetSdkVersion 9
}

lintOptions {
    abortOnError false
}
}
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

The error log is:

```
    org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':Firebase:processDebugGoogleServices'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:100)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:70)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.execute(OutputDirectoryCreatingTaskExecuter.java:51)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskOutputCachingStateExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:60)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:97)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.execute(CleanupStaleOutputsExecuter.java:87)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.run(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:248)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:241)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:230)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:123)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.access$200(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:104)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.execute(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:626)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.executeWithTask(DefaultTaskExecutionPlan.java:581)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:98)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:63)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:46)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
        at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:55)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: org.gradle.api.GradleException: No matching client found for package name 'com.google.firebase.unity'
        at com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesTask.action(GoogleServicesTask.java:123)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:73)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.doExecute(StandardTaskAction.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:39)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.StandardTaskAction.execute(StandardTaskAction.java:26)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:780)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:747)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter$1.run(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:121)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:336)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$RunnableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:328)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
        at org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:110)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:92)
        ... 32 more
```

I am building with gradle for the first time and do not know much about it.

Comment: print the whloe error log

Comment: It means your app's application ID is "com.google.firebase.unity", but that same string wasn't found in your google-services.json file.  please check that

Comment: @krishankTripathi In google-services.json file, the package name is "com.DefaultCompany.Data_Collection" which is the applicationID in project/build.gradle . I configured firebase database(while developing in unity) with this application ID.

Comment: you did not print the full log like Error excecution failed for what?

Comment: are you using the google-services.json that you genereate from the firebase or not

Comment: Please print for which task the error is like Error Excecution Failed for task: ???? please always put the detail info when asking a question

Comment: @krishankTripathi I have added the error log. I am using google-services.json that firebase generated.

Comment: try to remove apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services' from gradle file and rebuild your project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use **firebase unity plugin**, you will find a python code that can convert google-services.json to google-services.xml.(**I think You already have it**)

**When you have this xml, you don't need apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'**

Try to remove it and rebuild your project I hope it will run for sure.

Comment: This solution removed the error mentioned in the question. But, I have gotten additional errors. Should I post the error in this question or open another question and post the link here?

Comment: The link to the question addressing the new errors is [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49709595/error-while-building-unity-projecthaving-firebase-in-android-studio)